# OWB – Reuse Mapping for Different Data Sources

Tags: mapping, reusability, oracle-warehouse-builder

I have a PERSON table in 5 different schema namely : A, B, C, D and E. It has exact sme structure.

In OWB target schema, a mapping PERSON_MAP is defined, which uses A.PERSON table.

I want to reuse this mapping PERSON_MAP, to use with different source schema (B, C, D and E)

How can I do this in OWB UI and with OMB+ commands?

Answer (score 1):

I will describe in steps what you should do:

1. Define a synonym PERSON which points to the A.PERSON table

   CREATE SYNONYM PERSON FOR A.PERSON;
2. Open the database metadata import wizard, check *Use a synonym to look up objects* option and import PERSON synonym.
3. Now when you generate intermediate script from your mapping you will see that it will use synonym name from the local schema.
4. Deploy mapping
5. To reuse mapping for different source schema you should change the synonym definition and point to any schema as long as the table structure is the same.

   CREATE OR REPLACE SYNONYM PERSON FOR B.PERSON;

When you execute mapping it will process data from the source table behind the synonym.

Answer (score 0):

In Design Center;

You can create copies of PERSON_MAP as PERSON_MAP_B and PERSON_MAP_C and so on.

Take one copy for example PERSON_MAP_B.

Right-click the mapping and select "Configure".

In the Configuration view; 
  Go to "Table Operators"; 
  Expand the source table; "B";
  Change the "Location" to source of B.